# swapon has no effect, /proc/swaps remains empty

Tags: swap

My Ubuntu server has no more than 512 MB of memory. It is not enough for running Node.js + MongoDB.

Hence I decided to add a swap file:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/myswapfile bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 4.69263 s, 229 MB/s
# mkswap /root/myswapfile
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1048572 KiB
no label, UUID=3c64da32-d0b4-49e5-92db-fba961b8ae28
# swapon /root/myswapfile
```

No error message => successful!

The new swap file should now be listed, **but it is not**:

```
# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
```

(empty list)

How can I make it work? What might be the reason for the missing swap?

Comment: Try to move swap file to root of partition aka `/`

Comment: When I first tried it, I tried it with _/swapfile_

Comment: Change permision `chmod 600 /root/myswapfile` then again `swapon /root/myswapfile`

Comment: That did not help... Interesting notice: I need to swapoff before I swapon, even though swap never appears in the list.

Comment: does ```free```show any swap usage?

Comment: `free` shows `0 0 0` for Swap

Comment: What about ownership of the swap file ? is it `root root` ?

Comment: Does anything show in `dmesg` after adding swap? It may get something like `Adding 4748284k swap on /dev/sda11.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4748284k FS`

Comment: I moved it to / again: `-rw------- 1 root root 1.0G Jul 30 19:46 /myswapfile`

Comment: `dmesg` output and _/var/log/dmesg_ are empty

Comment: same problem here (even up to the point where dmesg shows no content). Did you ever resolve this? Can swapping maybe be somehow disabled in the kernel?

Comment: unfortunately not... I had to rent a second server which includes swap in its Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 9):

First, erase your original swapfile:

```
sudo rm /myswapfile
```

Next, run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
ls -lh /swapfile
```

The output should be similar to the following:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1.0G Aug  3 18:20 /swapfile
```

Now, run the following commands:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo swapon -s
```

Now, edit /etc/fstab to make the changes permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add the following line to the end of the file:

```
/swapfile    none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

---

If that still doesn't work, you may want to check swappiness:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

This command should return a number. The default should be 60.

If no output, run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60
echo "vm.swappiness = 60" | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The `-a` **is important** after `tee` or **you will overwrite the entire file!!!**

Answer (score 1):

You swap file should be in /swapfile with 600 rights.

```
#moving file and changing rights
sudo mv /root/myswapfile /myswapfile
sudo chmod 600 /myswapfile

sudo mkswap /myswapfile
```

**add swap file. I think you forget this command**

```
sudo swapon /myswapfile
#check swap is working
sudo swapon -s
```

Comment: The chmod command needs to be `sudo chmod 600...`. It may also be worthwhile making it owned by root: `sudo chown root:root ...`.

Comment: If you see main post of @user22611 use see that he works as root.

Comment: `makeswap` → `mkswap`

Comment: @user22611 yes. You are right. mkswap and chmod.

Comment: @UNIm95 - you can [edit] your post to fix these issues....

Answer (score 1):

Use `fdisk` to create a swap. Add a new partition, select Linux swap, write the changes.
`mkswap /dev/sd?`
You need to add it to your `/etc/fstab/`. Change XXX to the swap UUID.

```
UUID=XXX none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Run `swapon -a` to make it available from `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score -1):

you could do this:

```
sudo umount -a
gedit /etc/fstab
```

and write in where swap is this:

```
/proc/swap     proc   default  errors=noremount     1
```

and then this:

```
sudo mount -a
```

and then run gpart and set the swap drive as swap, and mount it on the root dev drive, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Err... doesn't `sudo umount -a` unmount EVERYTHING? (which may break stuff if in use) If you are trying to unmount existing swap things first it may be better to find them in `mount` and then unmount them specifically, or use `sudo swapoff -a`.

Comment: it is what i did souldn't break any of what you made, and it is the only thing to do.

Comment: Running `umount -a` is indeed a really dumb idea. Unmount what you need to unmount, not everything.